# check associative array values with values from another associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to find the continent code for each phone number. 
for this, I have an associative array with country phone code and continent code.
like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [continent] => EU
        [Phone] => 376
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [continent] => AS
        [Phone] => 971
    )
   )
```

I have tried to use this array to check the location of each phone number 
that I get from this array

```
 Array
 (
    [0] => Array
    (
   [customer_id] => 1273
   [dialed] => 44414307935, 1768036761
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [customer_id] => 1536
        [dialed] => 52228169542
    )
   )
```

I think that I want to get a new associative array because I want to send this data to SQL table later

so I have tried to loop trow the array and check the number but I can't loop trow the phone number array

```
        foreach ($cells as $row) {
        // Get Every Phone Number Array
            foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
            #List of all phone number arrays:
            // Get cCodes
            foreach ($cCode as $key => $value) {

                if (substr($row['dialed'], 0, strlen($key)) == $key) {
                    $phoneNum[$row['customer_id']] = [
                        $val => $value
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($phoneNum);
```

I'm not able to loop trow the actual phone number arrays.

my dream I getting an array with customer id as the key and the numbers and continent code as values
but all I get is

```
  Array
 (
  [1273] => Array
    (
        [44414307935, 1768036761] => Array
            (
                [continent] => AF
                [Phone] => 225
            )

    )
   )
```

when I'm adding loop to get all of the phone numbers I'm getting an error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
   foreach ($cells as $row) {
        // Get Every Phone Number Array
        foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
            #List of all phone number arrays:
            // Get cCodes
            foreach ($row['dialed'] as $num) {
                foreach ($cCode as $key => $value) {
                    if (substr($num, 0, strlen($key)) == $key) {
                        $phoneNum[$row['customer_id']] = [
                            $val => $value
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($phoneNum);
```

Comment: A key cannot be array-type.  Some dreams cannot come true.  `[44414307935, 1768036761] => Array`  We are going to need you to change your dream.  I am struggling to find any relationship between your two sample arrays to be merged.  Where did `AF` magically come from?

Comment: this is the problem. there is no relationship. this is what I'm trying to create using the id.

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

This error means that the variable you're using in the foreach() function isn't an array.

It seems that `$row['dialed']` is not an array, rather a string with comma-separated values.

> [dialed] => 44414307935, 1768036761

So, before this line:

```
foreach ($row['dialed'] as $num) {
```

Add the following:

```
$row['dialed'] = explode(",", $row['dialed']);
```

Which convert that string into an array.

---

Regards your end goal - rethink on WHAT you actually need. As @mickmackusa mentioned, it's not really achievable but there's a better way to accomplish your requirements for sure. Why would you want an array to be as a key to another array in your case? Does it make sense?

Think on a better data structure. Consider the goal of your code and the relations between the data items.

Comment: yes. i'm starting to think that the problem is my data structure.